# How to make numbered dingbats left aligned in a stylesheet

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, cells, customization

I use cell dingbats and counters in my stylesheet to auto number certain cells.  For example, in my private stylesheet I defined the "Outline1" cell style as:

```
Cell[StyleData["Outline1"],
CellDingbat->Cell[TextData[StyleBox[{CounterBox["Outline1"],"."},Bold]]],
CellMargins->{{50,10},{7,7}},
ReturnCreatesNewCell->True,
StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"Outline2"},
CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 40},
ParagraphIndent->0,
LineSpacing->{1,0},
MenuSortingValue->1250,
MenuCommandKey->"2",
CounterIncrements->"Outline1",
CounterAssignments->{{"Outline2",0}},
MenuSortingValue->50,
DefaultReturnCreatedCellStyle->"Outline1"],
```

This works great.  When I create a new "outline1" cell, Mathematica automatically places the counter dingbat to the left of the cell.  See pic below.

[image]

The only thing I don't like is that the counters are right aligned in front of each cell.  You can see this when the counter goes from 9 to 10.  I would like to the counters to be left aligned as follows.

[image]

How do I alter the stylesheet code given above to make this happen?

Comment: Have you seen [`\[AlignmentMarker]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/AlignmentMarker.html)?

Comment: Thanks Edumund.  Yes I work with them.  Alignment markers only work with grid structures (with rows and columns).   My question does not pertain to grid structures.  My question pertains to rows of cells each of which has a cell dingbats in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't adjust itself for 10 digits numbers but a quick fix is to use:

```
CellDingbat -> Cell[ BoxData[ 
    PaneBox[
       StyleBox[RowBox[{CounterBox["Outline1"],"."}],Bold],
       Alignment->Left,ImageSize->30 (*less than cell margin*)
    ]
]]
```

Comment: Using BoxData with PaneBox makes a lot of sense. Most of what I have learned in Mathematica is from you helpful advice over the past year.  Thanks again Kuba. You are a wealth of knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Thank you for kind words and I'm glad it works for you. :)